# .Value returns only 4 decimal places of a value in currency format

Tags: vba, excel, currency, regional-settings

I have the following VBA function to retrieve a currency value from somewhere else with the same column but a different row:

```
Function GetValue(RefCell As Range) As Double

    Dim i As Integer

    i = Application.Caller.Column - RefCell.Column

    Obtain = RefCell.Offset(0, i).Value

End Function
```

And here's the setup:

```
Column1 | Column2
Test 1  | 0.11111
Test 2  | $0.11111
```

Using GetValue(Test1) gave me $0.11111 with all 5 decimal places. However, GetValue(Test2) yield $0.11110 with only the first 4 decimals. How come the function only returns 4 decimal places if the input is in Currency format as opposed to Number format? I want to retrieve the most accurate number with all the decimal places from cells with Currency format - ie $0.1111**1** as opposed to $0.1111**0**.

Comment: You've redacted your code a smidge too much. Shouldn't that be `GetValue = RefCell.Offset(0, i).Value` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Range.Value property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195193.aspx) holds some regional currency idiosyncrasies; one of these could be a 4 digit precision (common for some regional currency variable types).

Use the [Range.Value2 property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193553.aspx) for the raw double value.

```
GetValue = RefCell.Offset(0, i).Value2
```

The returned value may have to be manually formatted as currency; any regional information has been stripped.